# QtMultimedia 5.0: change playbackRate

Tags: video, qml, qt5, frame-rate

I'm trying to change at run-time and in a very smooth way the playbackRate (fps) of a video. This is a small qml example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Video {
    id: video
    source: "Wildlife.wmv"
    width: 800
    height: 600
    volume: 0
    autoPlay: true
    playbackRate: 0.1 // <--- no effect

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            animatePlaybackRate.start() // <--- hangs the video
        }
    }

    NumberAnimation {
        id: animatePlaybackRate
        target: video
        properties: "playbackRate"
        from: 0.1
        to: 2.0
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        duration: 10000
        easing {
            type: Easing.Linear 
        }
    }
}
```

Please, may you suggest me a way to do this? I found a drawback using plain Qt4 (C++, no qml) and GStreamer, but I really want to use the power of qml for the other features of the application.